# Multiple Wells in a Bootstrap row Not behaving as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, row

I am trying to have two wells right next to each other in a boorstrap row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 well">
            Some Text Here
        </div>
        <div class="span4 well">
            Some Nav Here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The span4 always gets displayed below span8 and not along it as I would expect. How can I get them to show up right next to each other instead of one below the other. I have tried to give a max-width: 100% to the .well class but that has not helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite you `html` with the following way:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="well">Some Text Here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="well">Some Nav Here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```